# Java URI#resolve improperly resolves relative URLs in certain cases

Tags: java, uri

I'm writing my own web crawler in Java, and I'm using [URI#resolve](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#resolve%28java.lang.String%29) to resolve URLs that appear on every HTML page that my crawler encounters. In certain cases, it's behaving in an unexpected way.

For example, while crawling https://hacks.mozilla.org, I notice that one of the URLs extracted is https://hacks.mozilla.orgabout/ (indeed, if you look at the HTML source for that page, you will find an `<a href="about/">`). I did some testing, and got these results:

```
URI uri1 = new URI("https://hacks.mozilla.org").resolve("about/");
System.out.println(uri1); // => https://hacks.mozilla.orgabout/

URI uri2 = new URI("https://hacks.mozilla.org/").resolve("about/");
System.out.println(uri2); // => https://hacks.mozilla.org/about/
```

I don't know how practical it is to attempt to mitigate this issue by manually adding the slash after the base URL, but I want to know if there is an actual non-hacky fix to this problem.

I did a little more experimentation, and realized that this happens when the path element is empty (null or 0-length string):

```
URI uri3 = new URI("http", null, "hacks.mozilla.org", 80, "", null, null).resolve("about/");
System.out.println(uri3); // => http://hacks.mozilla.org:80about/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URI constructor Javadoc states that (from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) :

> If a path is given then it is appended. Any character not in the unreserved, punct, escaped, or other categories, and not equal to the slash character ('/') or the commercial-at character ('@'), is quoted.

So just filling this parameter with one of those accepted character will solve your problem.

Comment: I see. I ended up doing `new URI(uri.getScheme(), uri.getUserInfo(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), "/", uri.getQuery(), uri.getFragment());` to mitigate the problem.